# onchange event of select box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using a selectbox to display the list of "enterpirses" from the database. But the onchange event is not triggering. But when i manually once put the value of querystring then it starts working. I dont understand why it is happening.

I am new to javascript and php, kindly suggest me the solution to this.

```
<select id="enterprisebox" onchange="javascript:valueselect()" >
    <option value="-">-</option>

    <?php foreach($enterprise as $val) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $val['customer_id'];?>"><?php echo $val['customer_name']?>
    </option>
    <? } ?>

</select>
```

and my javascript is--

```
function valueselect()
{
    var i = document.getElementById('enterprisebox');
    var p = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
    //alert(p);
    window.location.href = "channelinformation.html?selected="+p;
}
```

Comment: is your alert is working ??? is it triggered on change ??

Comment: @Ramesh alert works when i manually put any valid value in querystring in the url and then change the value of selectbox. Everything works after that, but this should not happen i guess.

Comment: Has it displayed your customer_id in alert box ?? ok am gonna place a code in answer's list try that one. ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onchange="javascript:valueselect()"` replace with `onchange="valueselect(this.value);"`

```
function valueselect(myval)
{
      window.location.href = "channelinformation.html?selected="+myaval;
}
```

You Can Use Directly

```
onchange="window.location='channelinformation.html?selected='+myaval"
```

Comment: this is also not working, can you suggest me some way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Make life easier and use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#enterprisebox').change(function () {
       window.location.href = "channelinformation.html?selected="+ $(this).val();
    });    

});
```

Comment: I see no real benefit to using jQuery in this case... only the downside of having your user download the full lib when visiting your page, just because the developer was lazy. Besides, did I miss the jQuery tag or is it just not there?

Comment: Stop giving answers as "use jQuery instead".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<select id="enterprisebox" onchange="javascript:valueselect(this)" >
    <option value="-">-</option>

    <?php foreach($enterprise as $val) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $val['customer_id'];?>"><?php echo $val['customer_name']?>
    </option>
    <? } ?>

</select>

<script>
   function valueselect(sel) {
      var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
      window.location.href = "channelinformation.html?selected="+value;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, Ravi Jethva also suggested the same method above. Thanx to both of you