# redirect to different URL with same form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i am new to PHP and trying to arrive with similar [functionality given in URL](http://bankifsccode.com/BASSEIN_CATHOLIC_CO-OP_BANK_LTD).

i have a form with four select options, result will be retrived when last option selected.

my current code is :

```
{
  $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

  if(!$result)    
    echo mysql_error();

  $option = "";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $option .= '<option value = "'.str_replace(' ', '_', $row['bankname']).'">'.$row['bankname'].'</option>';
  }

  str_replace(' ', '_', $row['bankname'])  
?>

<form method = "POST" action = "">

<select name = "bank" onChange="document.location.href=bank[selectedIndex].value">
<?php echo $option; ?> 

</select>

</form>

}
```

Probably i am asking very high level question, but please help.

Regards,
Anitha

Comment: <form method = "POST" action = "">

   <select name = "bank" onChange="document.location.href=bank[selectedIndex].value">
                <?php echo $option; ?> 

 </select>

</form>

Comment: So when user selects last option from the dropdown, only than it should redirect?

Comment: Are you asking about replacing the target url dynamically for the form ?

Comment: $('select:last').change(function(){ location.href=$(this).val() });
So when you select anything from the last dropdown, only than it will redirect to the selected option. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: In order for it to redirect, you could either have the page reload and get the specified choice from $_POST or you can use JavaScript to grab the choice and redirect.  It depends on if you want an immediate reaction (JavaScript) or a code entirely comprised of php and HTML.

Comment: hope this link would be helpful for you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122047/onchange-event-of-select-box

Comment: i just need the same functionality given in http://www.bankifsccode.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the first time using ajax, and whem the ajax is sucess you can change the submit the form again returning true.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right, you are not looking for loading options into select box, but trying to look for a solution where the last select box have values:

```
    <select id = 'finalSelect'>
        <option value='http://aaaa.com'>A<option>
        <option value='http://bbbb.com'>B<option>
        <option value='http://cccc.com'>C<option>
    </select>
```

and based on the user selection your page should redirect to aaaa.com, bbbb.com or cccc.com.

If I am right about your requirement, all you have to do is:

```
    <select id = 'finalSelect' ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;>
        <option value='http://aaaa.com'>A<option>
        <option value='http://bbbb.com'>B<option>
        <option value='http://cccc.com'>C<option>
    </select>
```